# Got String Data from Internal Storage When i set it to listview only last item is displayed

Tags: android, listview

**Got String Data from Internal Storage.When i tried to display that data on listview only last item is displayed.
Here is my code.**

```
 listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);


    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/storage/sdcard0/client_new.txt")));
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String str = s.next();
            char[] myChar = str.toCharArray();
            System.out.println(myChar);
            String str_new = String.valueOf(myChar);
            String[] items={str_new};
            final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
            {
                list.add(items[i]);
            }

            Toast.makeText(ExistingContacts.this,str_new,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  final ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); before while loop

```
listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);


    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/storage/sdcard0/client_new.txt")));
final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String str = s.next();
            char[] myChar = str.toCharArray();
            System.out.println(myChar);
            String str_new = String.valueOf(myChar);
            String[] items={str_new};

            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
            {
                list.add(items[i]);
            }

            Toast.makeText(ExistingContacts.this,str_new,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Deepak Sachdeva i got output.